# Passing a line of text to a return method

Tags: java

I am working on building a small program.  I want a user to enter a line of text (done in main method), and for his or her line of text to be passed to another method (reverse) that I wrote (larger idea is that I will use the reverse method to reverse the string letter by letter).

As if it is not humbling enough, I am having a bit of a block in the simple function of passing a value (the user's line of text) from the main method to my return method.  Can anyone give me a bit of help?

Below is a shell of the code, and is not near finished yet.  Thanks.

```
import java.util.*;

public class Test {

public static void main(String[] args) {
Scanner console = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.print("Type in a line of text here: ");
String statement = console.next();
// What is a good way to send the line of text from the user, to the reverse method       below?

}

public static String reverse(String sentence) {
// I have not built this method yet.
}

}
```

Comment: Note: `console.next()` returns just one "token" of input.  If you type in a line with more than one word, `console.next()` just returns the first word.  Use `console.nextLine()` if you want the entire line.

Answer (score 2):

To read entire line change

```
String statement = console.next();
```

to

```
String statement = console.nextLine();
```

Now `statement` will contain entire line and you can use it as

```
String reversed = reverse(statement);
```

Since `reverse` method is static and declared inside `Test` class normally you would ave to call it with `Test.reverse(argument)`, but since you are calling it inside class in which this method is declared you can skip class name part.

Answer (score 1):

I believe that your problem can be solved by using

```
String statement = console.nextLine();
```

And then calling

```
reverse(statement);
```

Answer (score 1):

just call reverse(statement) once you've read from Scanner

Answer (score 0):

```
...
String statement = console.nextLine();

String reversed = reverse(statement);

System.out.print("Your reversed statement: " + reversed);
```

- http://www.wikihow.com/Call-a-Method-in-Java
- http://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Java_Programming/Methods